# Java: Window.setAlwaysOnTop not working Linux

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a Swing application and I am trying to sit it over the top of other windows however when I run the application which is using Window.setAlwaysOnTop(true) it works fine in Windows but doesn't work in Linux (Redhat Enterprise). Any ideas?

Comment: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6380835

Comment: Which version of Java you are using?

Comment: I'm using Java 1.6 u18

Comment: I am not sure about this but try for java 7 or higher.